# Exclude countries dynamically amCharts

Tags: amcharts, ammap

I want to exclude countries from map (amCharts v4 maps) dynamically. But when I push values into polygon series nothing changes. `polygonSeries.exclude.push('RU');`. I must redraw a map to see new excluded countries. How to exclude countries without reloading the map?. See example in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/besokakulia/pen/bOBzEq?editors=1111). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, instead of excluding, using "hide" function `polygonSeries.getPolygonById("RU").hide();`.